# Complex initialization for a const variable while avoiding new allocation

Tags: c++, reference, initialization, constants

I'm trying to initialize `const&` variable. The value of a the variable I'm trying to initialize depends on some condition.
For example:

```
typedef std::vector<string> string_vector;
string_vector data_pool;

const string& data;
if( some_cond )
  {
    // do something and set data
    data = data_pool[some_index1]
  }
 else
   {
     // do something and set data
    data = data_pool[some_index2]
   }
```

Of course the code above is not valid, but this is what I'm trying to do.

I can use `ternary operator`:

```
const string& data = (some_cond)? data_pool[some_index1] : data_pool[some_index2];
```

but this syntax doesn't really let me do anything other than to set the value.

So now I try to use `lambda expression` (not too sure I got it right):

```
const string& data = [&]{

    string tmp = "";  
      {
        // do something and set tmp
        tmp = data_pool[some_index1]
      }
    else
      {
        // do something and set tmp
        tmp = data_pool[some_index2]
      }

    return tmp;
}
```

but my problem here is that this solution **requires new string allocation** which I cannot afford at this point since this piece of code is the bottle neck of my program.

***Question***
How can `data` be initialize in a complex manner **but efficiently**?

***Note***
I can workaround the problem quite easily. `data` will eventually refer to some item in `data_pool` so all I need to do is to calculate the desired index and then initialize `data`.  However I'm not interested in the workaround but rather in an elegant technique/practice for this elementary issue. what if the initialization is a bit more complex than calculating some index in a vector.

Comment: what would be the signature of such function?

Comment: `std::string initString`. A `const` reference can bind to a temporary.

Comment: but this will also allocate new string for the returned value which I'd like to avoid. what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using a function or a lambda. Both solution can be done so that no allocation is performed and the const reference actually alias the data present in `data_pool`.

With a function, that'd be:

```
const std::string& initConstString(string_vector& pool){
    std::size_t index;

    //complex initialization stuff

    return pool[index];
}
```

With a lambda:

```
auto lambda = [&data_pool]() -> const std::string&{
    std::size_t index = 0;//For the sake of example
    //perform initialization here
    return data_pool[index];
};

const std::string& constString = lambda();
```

[**Live example for the lambda version on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba6b2e389e06876d)

I'd personally prefer the function if the initialization represents lot (well, > 4-5 lines) as I like my lambdas to be short and concise, but that's up to you.